# Android on Click from other method

Tags: java, android

so I want to use a method that saves my string from the textfield to be my onClick for a button in an other class, but it is a non-static method. How can i manage to do it? 
Here's the method i want to have as the onClick action

```
public void addToLvStart(View v){
    EditText titledisplay = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titledisplay);
    namesAdapter.add(titledisplay.getText().toString());
    titledisplay.setText("");
    saveNames();
        }
```

saveNames is also non-static

Comment: not clear what exactly you want, all i can say to use shared preference for saving string and then use it in any class.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it on the xml definition of your button

```
android:onClick="addToLvStart"
```

You can also add a click listener from code:

```
button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        addToLvStart();
    }
 });
```

Comment: The problem being i cannot use onClick for methods from other classes, addToLvStart is in a different class than the xml file with the button belongs to

Comment: Even if your method was in your activity I would not recommend setting the click listener in the XML. It's easier to review and understand your code if you set your listeners in your code.

Comment: if addToLvStart is in a different class then the findViewById shouldn't work as well